# How to use the takeScreenshot() method present in TraCICommandInterface.h?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to do simulation in OMNeT++ and I have used Veins and SUMO as well in the simulation, but I have got this error:

> Model error: TraCI Server reported error executing command 0xcc("View
>   '#0' is not known")..

I am using the header file `TraCICommandInterface.h` and in that using the below mentioned class

```
class GuiView {
public:
GuiView(TraCICommandInterface* traci, std::string viewId) : traci(traci), viewId(viewId) {
connection = &traci->connection;
}
void setScheme(std::string name);
void setZoom(double zoom);
void setBoundary(Coord p1, Coord p2);
void takeScreenshot(std::string filename = "");
protected:
TraCICommandInterface* traci;
TraCIConnection* connection;
std::string viewId;
};
GuiView guiView(std::string viewId) {
return GuiView(this, viewId);
}
```

I am trying to use the `takeScreenshot()` function but in order to do so first I am creating an object of this class using GuiView `guiView(std::string viewId)`.
So my question is what is `viewId`?

Answer (score 1):

The `viewId` refers to which SUMO window to take a screenshot of.

For example, [this screenshot](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/File:Scr_koeln_fastlane.gif)
shows five views. Visible in the window titles are their names: here,
they are called `View #0` to `View #4`.